# Verifying that a functions attends values below something

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

After plotting the graph of  $$f(x)=\frac{π}{3\sqrt{2 π}} (\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{18}}}{3} + \frac{e^{\frac{-(x - 5)^2}{2}}}{1} +\frac{e^{\frac{-(x - 15)^2}{8}}}{2} 
   ) (1 + x^2)$$

I would like to verify with mathematica that $f(x)<20$,   for $\vert{x}\vert>20$ . So I write in the notebook:

```
Solve[π/(3 Sqrt[2 π]) (E^(-x^2/18)/3 + E^(-(x - 5)^2/2) + 
        E^(-(x - 15)^2/8)/2) (1 + x^2) < 10 && Abs[x] > 20, Reals]]]
```

and then I get the message that

> Solve::fulldim: The solution set contains a full-dimensional
>   component; use Reduce for complete solution information.

On the other hand WolphramAlfa gives me the answer.

Can you please tell me what I did wrong here? Is there another way to check this inequality?
Thanks.

Comment: Reduce[\[Pi]/(3 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) (E^(-x^2/18)/3 + E^(-(x - 5)^2/2) + 
      E^(-(x - 15)^2/8)/2) (1 + x^2) < 10 && Abs[x] > 20, Reals]

Comment: @Moo, Thanks it works now...To be honest I wrote also Reduce[ ] ... but outside of Solve[ ]  .

Comment: `Maximize[{f[x], Abs[x] > 20}, x, Reals] //
  Simplify // Quiet` indicates that for `Abs[x] > 20` the function is below about `3.6803`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** since the question indicates one thing and the code indicates another.

Reduce can get pretty exact.
Your question asks for `f[x]<20`, but you code tries to solve `f[x]<10`.

```
f[x_] = π/(3 Sqrt[2 π]) (E^(-x^2/18)/3 + E^(-(x - 5)^2/2) + 
    E^(-(x - 15)^2/8)/2) (1 + x^2)
```

If you mean `f[x]<20`

```
Reduce[f[x] < 20] // N
(*x < 12.8888 || x > 18.1476*)
```

which proves your premise and then some.

If you mean `f[x]<10`

```
Reduce[f[x] < 10] // N
(*x < 4.67464 || 6.01107 < x < 12.0177 || x > 19.0257*)
```

which also supports your premise.

Comment: I believe that you meant `Reduce[f[x] < 10] // N`; in which case, there are three intervals. The outer intervals being the ones of interest.

Comment: Actually I keyed off your question. f[x]<20. 10 is not mentioned in your question.  Is that a typo?

Comment: the `20` in my **comment** was a constraint on `Abs[x]` not on `f[x]`. The OP's `Solve` constrained `f[x] < 10`. Since the maximum for `f[x]` with `Abs[x] > 20` is about `3.6803` this shows that the constraint of `f[x] < 10` is met.

Comment: I looked at the statement right under the OP s top equation. I was not making any comment on your statements. His question contains f[x]<20.

Comment: Sorry, I just went with his code.

Comment: One is evidently a typo.  Hard to tell which one though.

Comment: Following your conversation,  I do not really care about to "solve" the system of inequalities, i.e to find the exact intervals where f is below 20. I want just to be sure that f is below 20 outside of the interval [-20, 20] .

Answer (score 1):

Here is "visual" verification with confirmation that your interval $|x|>20$ is contained in solution interval for which $f(x)<20$:

```
f[x_] := \[Pi]/(3 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) (E^(-x^2/18)/3 + E^(-(x - 5)^2/2) + 
    E^(-(x - 15)^2/8)/2) (1 + x^2)
np = NumberLinePlot[{RealAbs[x] > 20, 
    r = Reduce[f[x] < 20, x]}, {x, -20, 20}];
p = Plot[f[x], {x, -30, 30}, 
   GridLines -> {{r[[1, 2]], r[[2, 2]]}, {20}}, PlotRange -> Full];
Show[p, np]
IntervalMemberQ[
 Interval[{-Infinity, r[[1, 2]]}, {r[[2, 2]], Infinity}], 
 Interval[{-Infinity, -20}, {20, Infinity}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice graphics!  Actually,  how do you copy from notebook of mathematica and paste it to stack exchange?

Comment: @dmtri I just use a screen capture software Jing. There are many others and mine is an old version. Just suffices for me.